# Error when using dropdown (html) for selecting MYSQL query

Tags: php, mysql

I am getting this error when loading the webpage:

> Notice: Undefined index: bandselection in
> /public/sites/www.transport-dealer.com/commercialequipmentfinder/index.php
> on line 203
>
> Notice: Undefined index: bandselection2 in
> /public/sites/www.transport-dealer.com/commercialequipmentfinder/index.php
> on line 204

When i press submit it will show the correct data, is there anyway to make sure the data in the "seleccted"part of the form is already been filtered and shown

HTML:

```
 <form method="post" action="index.php">
   <label>
     <select name="bandselection" id="bandselection">
       <option value="1990" selected="selected">1990</option>
       <option value="2006">2006</option>
       <option value="2005">2005</option>
       <option value="2004">2004</option>
     </select>
     <select name="bandselection2" id="bandselection2">
       <option value="2015" selected="selected">2015</option>
       <option value="2006">2006</option>
       <option value="2005">2005</option>
       <option value="2004">2004</option>
     </select>
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" />  
  </label>
</form>
```

PHP:

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
$bandselection = $_POST['bandselection'];
$bandselection2 = $_POST['bandselection2'];
$sql = "SELECT ID, link, link_image, modelyear, brand, city, price, description, country, type FROM semi_trailer_curtainsider  WHERE modelyear BETWEEN  '" . $bandselection ."' AND '" . $bandselection2 ."' AND brand = 'Samro'";
```

Comment: On initial page load your `$_POST` variables are not set, which will cause the issue. Wrap that section in a `if(isset($_POST['bandselection'])){ ... }` to prevent the warnings.

Comment: Hi, many thanks :) this really helped and sorry that i was not able to find a other post that was the same. i did not know how to phrase the question correct

Answer (score 0):

That's because the superglobal `$_POST` is not populated yet when you load the page (because it is an HTTP `GET` request), you should process the form data in another PHP file by setting the `action` attribute on the `<form>` tag like this:

```
<form action="other_page.pho">
```

And/Or by checking the `$_POST` array is populated before processing it:

```
if(isset($_POST['my_data'])){
      //process form
}
```

Comment: Hi many thanks for helping, i already got the awnser from @sean